# when I close my opengl view my program crashes

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a QT application, in this i creator one opengl view, but when i close my opengl view( by pressing the exit button or 'ESC') my Qt aplication close too, I know is if it is a crash or only a close my program.

this is one peace of my call to opengl

```
int a = qApp->arguments().
char *av = qApp->arguments().toVector().data()->toLocal8Bit().
initializeGL(&a, &av);
glutMainLoop();
```

and this is my InitializeGL():

```
void ImagemFestival::initializeGL(int * pargc, char ** argv)
{
    tempoIncio = std::clock();

    glutInit(pargc, argv);
    //glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(GL_WIN_SIZE_X, GL_WIN_SIZE_Y);
    glutCreateWindow ("User Tracker Viewer");
    //glutFullScreen();
    glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE);

    glutKeyboardFunc(glutKeyboard);
    glutDisplayFunc(glutDisplay);
    glutIdleFunc(glutIdle);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}
```

and this my glutDisplay():

```
void ImagemFestival::glutDisplay (void)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -30);

    // Setup the OpenGL viewpoint

    glLoadIdentity();
    //char texto[6];

    xn::SceneMetaData sceneMD;
    xn::DepthMetaData depthMD;
    g_DepthGenerator.GetMetaData(depthMD);
#ifndef USE_GLES
    glOrtho(0, depthMD.XRes(), depthMD.YRes(), 0, -1.0, 1.0);
#else
    glOrthof(0, depthMD.XRes(), depthMD.YRes(), 0, -1.0, 1.0);
#endif

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    if (!g_bPause)
    {
        // Read next available data
        g_Context.WaitOneUpdateAll(g_UserGenerator);
    }

        // Process the data
        g_DepthGenerator.GetMetaData(depthMD);
        g_UserGenerator.GetUserPixels(0, sceneMD);
        if(tipoImagem == IMAGEM_FESTIVAL_TIPO_FESTIVAL){
            DrawDepthMap(depthMD, sceneMD);
        }
        else{
            cv::Mat fotoRgb;
            DrawRgbMap(depthMD, sceneMD,&fotoRgb);
            imwrite("/home/vinicius/fotosKinect/imagem--2.jpg", fotoRgb);
        }


#ifndef USE_GLES
    char texto[32];
    tempoFloat =  10.0-float(std::clock()-tempoIncio)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC*0.8);
    //Exibindo Tempo
    snprintf(texto,sizeof(texto),"%d",(int)(tempoFloat));
    textoTela(texto,0.0f,20.0f);
    glutSwapBuffers();
#endif

}
```

Comment: Qt has its own event loop and GLWidget that you should use, there's no real need to use glut with QT

Comment: My opengl view is a display for kinect image, for this i use one exemplo from OpenNI library. I do not know much about opengl, for this is very hard for me modify my class for new type.

Comment: Where does it crash? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: the crashe happens when closing the opengl view, but i don't know where specifically, you know i do stacktrace in Qt to be able to discover my error?